# Resize image on the fly by using Amazon Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I've followed the instructions of this article and it works as charm: 
https://aws.amazon.com/tw/blogs/compute/resize-images-on-the-fly-with-amazon-s3-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/

Instead of the resized image path format in the article: http://YOUR_BUCKET_WEBSITE_HOSTNAME_HERE/300x300/blue_marble.jpg

I would like it to be:
http://YOUR_BUCKET_WEBSITE_HOSTNAME_HERE/blue_marble_300.jpg

So I modified the index.js and upload the new function as below:

```
'use strict';

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const S3 = new AWS.S3({
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
});
const Sharp = require('sharp');

const BUCKET = process.env.BUCKET;
const URL = process.env.URL;

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    const key = event.queryStringParameters.key;
    const match = key.match(/([A-Za-z0-9/]*)((_\d+)?.([A-Za-z0-9/]*))$/);
    const size = match[2].split('.')[0].replace("_", "");
    let originalKey = key.replace("_" + size, "");
    console.log(originalKey);
    console.log(size);

    S3.getObject({ Bucket: BUCKET, Key: originalKey }).promise()
        .then(data => Sharp(data.Body)
            .resize(size, size)
            .toFormat('png')
            .toBuffer()
        )
        .then(buffer => S3.putObject({
            Body: buffer,
            Bucket: BUCKET,
            ContentType: 'image/png',
            Key: key,
        }).promise())
        .then(() => callback(null, {
            statusCode: '301',
            headers: { 'location': `${URL}/${key}` },
            body: '',
        }))
        .catch(err => callback(err));
}
```

But if failed as the error message:

```
{"message": "Internal server error"}
```

How should I implement this and debug? Btw I've checked the logs in cloud watch it shows

```
Syntax error in module 'index': SyntaxError
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

Comment: did you compile the sharp node module in Linux AMI, you need to compile sharp module in Linux AMI because lambda function runs on Amazon's Version of Linux

Comment: Sharp node module is not available globally, so need to upload it manually

Comment: @AnkitKumar I don't get it. Shouldn't the sample function include it already?

Comment: how you are bundling your code, i mean what are the contents, are you including the node_modules??

Comment: [Check This](http://sharp.dimens.io/en/latest/install/#aws-lambda)

Comment: if you need compiled version of Sharp module you can [check this](https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-sharp-image/tree/master/lambda-sharp/tarballs)]